# How to compare two files based on datetime?

Tags: c#

I need to compare two files based on datetime. I need to check whether these two files were created or modified with same datetime. I have used this code to read the datetime of files...

```
string fileName = txtfile1.Text;
var ftime = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName).ToString();
string fileName2 = txtfile2.Text;
var ftime2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName2).ToString();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Don't** convert the DateTime you receive from GetLastWriteTime() to string and compare the dates? Like.. if (ftime == ftime2) ..

Comment: Are you checking if they're the same date or do they have to be the same hour, minute and second too?

Comment: @jlafay:checking for same hour,minute and second

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't call `ToString()` on the `DateTime` values returned by `GetLastWriteTime()`. Do this instead:

```
DateTime ftime = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName);
DateTime ftime2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName2);
```

Then you can just compare `ftime` and `ftime2`:

```
if (ftime == ftime2)
{
   // Files were created or modified at the same time
}
```

Comment: ok I have more than one file inside two folders and i need to compare whether those files matches with datetime

Comment: @bala3569 This sounds like a different question entirely; can you provide some more detail or post another question?

Comment: This solution will not work for every file system - you cannot use it if you have a FAT or VFAT file system - which is often used for USB sticks - see my answer below to have a more general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how about doing

```
ftime == ftime2
```

? No need for the ToString though, better just compare DateTimes as-is.

Comment: ok I have more than one file inside two folders and i need to compare whether those files matches with datetime

Comment: For info for the OP: [DateTime Equality Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality.aspx) This shows that comparing two DateTimes does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The precision of the last modification time being stored in a file system varies between different file systems (VFAT, FAT, NTFS). So, its best to use an epsillon environment for this and either let the user choose a sensible value or choose a value based on the involved file systems.

https://superuser.com/questions/937380/get-creation-time-of-file-in-milliseconds

```
double epsillon = 2.0
DateTime lastUpdateA = File.GetLastWriteTime(filename);
DateTime lastUpdateB = File.GetLastWriteTime(filename2);

if (Math.Abs(Math.Round((lastUpdateA - lastUpdateB).TotalSeconds)) > epsillon)
 different = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

GetLastWriteTime() returns a DateTime object, so you can do this:

```
if (File.GetLastWriteTime(filename).CompareTo(File.GetLastWriteTime(filename2)) == 0)
```

to test if they have the same timestamp.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for more tips on comparing DateTime objects.

Comment: ok I have more than one file inside two folders and i need to compare whether those files matches with datetime

Answer (score -3):

```
bool isMatched=false;
int ia = string.Compare(ftime.ToString(), ftime2.ToString());
if (string.Compare(ftime.ToString(), ftime.ToString()) == 0)
    isMatched = true;
else
    isMatched = false;
```